# jquery plugin confirmOn use with live()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code. When I clicked on the button, this code returned confirm windows. All work.

But, when I want to click button, which load with ajax, confirm window doesn't return.

Please help me fix  this code.

```
 $('.button').confirmOn({
            questionText: 'Do you have a car?',
            textYes: 'Yes',
            textNo: 'No'
        },'click', function(e, confirmed) {
            if(confirmed){
               alert('You clicked "Yes"');
            }
        });
```

Comment: it binds it to the current 'button'. Instead, use delegated events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you have written your ajax function, but I am assuming that you are using jQuery for that. If yes then you can move your function into some wrapper function for eg.

```
function attachConfirmation() {
  $('.button').confirmOn({
        questionText: 'Do you have a car?',
        textYes: 'Yes',
        textNo: 'No'
    },'click', function(e, confirmed) {
        if(confirmed){
           alert('You clicked "Yes"');
        }
    });
}
```

And call this function on page load for the ".button" class which is not loaded by ajax load.

And again call this function on ajax success so that it will attach with ".button" which is rendered by ajax call.

But in this approach you need to be carefull since you are again calling this function on ajax success it will attach 2 events on previously rendered ".button".

For resolving this issue you can first remove the already attached even then attach it again in ajax success.For eg.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "some url",
   success: function() {
     $(".button").off("click");
     attachConfirmation();
   }
})
```

hope this may helps you.